# Okta sign-in widget with PHP does not work

Tags: okta, okta-api

I was trying to setup OAuth workflow using the sample application as given [here](https://developer.okta.com/code/php/quickstart-signin-widget.html)

However for some reason, after I enter my okta user Id and password, I never gets the control back on my call-back URL and application just hangs indefinitely.

However the normal Javascript Singn-in widget (check this [link](https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget.html)) with the minimal authentication does work and I get the control back to the redirect URL. **But this is not for an OAuth2 workflow... which is completely useless for me.** Because all it does is provide authentication service using Okta tenant app and it will redirect you to your App  URL. This does not provide any authorization grant workflow or other OAuth2 complex workflow. May be useful for some application but not for enterprise app where you want to retrieve user profiles, and create a login session based on user profile data retrieved from OKTA.

> **So my question is why is the OAuth workflow not working using the PHP application that uses JS sign-in-widget?** And why there are no instructions or warning on this page for this costly service (this is not free and many org is probably paying for this)?

I spent almost a day trying to setup my Authorization server as per the instruction given on this [link](https://developer.okta.com/code/php/quickstart-signin-widget.html), but nothing works. Any idea what must be going wrong ?

> Does this entire example works only after contacting OKTA support to enable the Authorization server feature? Because, I also saw a documentation [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/how-to/set-up-auth-server.html#overview) that says that this is Early Access (EA) feature (and it is probably recently added in OKTA? Extremely frustrating experience).

BTW I sent email to their customer support to enable this Authorization server feature just in case if I am missing something. If this does not work then I will have to create my own OAuth2 server using Laravel 5.4 PHP framework, which is probably the quickest solution and 100% free.

I also tried to test the Authorization server setup as per the instructions provided [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/how-to/set-up-auth-server.html#testing-an-openid-connect-flow).
I was successful in getting the following end point working:

```
/oauth2/:authorizationServerId/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

But I am unable to get any scope and claims using api end-point:

```
/api/v1/authorizationServers/:authorizationServerId/scopes
```

So in short, I am so far unable to test my Authorization server to get my authorization grant workflow working.

> Where can I look for some troubleshooting advice?
>
> Is there another way to check whether I have configured my OKTA Authorization server properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the JS script provided for the PHP sample is not right for the workflow I am working on. So after changing that JS Script, things started to work.

Edit: Also please note that Setting up Authorization server is a new feature (It is Early Access feature) in OKTA. It is not enabled by default. So you need to contact OKTA support team to enable the Authorization service endpoint and functionality provided by it.

Comment: Andy, Could you expand on "changing that JS Script"?  I'd like to use the sign in widget for a CakePHP plugin (similar use case to yours I believe) and have been struggling mightily.